# Why didn't we get any ENS event for air cancellation?

Tags: sabre

We've been having a PNR subscription for `Itinerary` `Ticketing/time limit` `Misc ticketing`. We've consistently received ENS event for ticketing but stopped receiving update on cancellation since Dec 22nd. We were told by support that our endpoint is sometime unreachable (without any failed request sample) or return status different than 202.

We've assessed our network and it shows a healthy status without any down time. Our logs show that we've responded with 202 for the ENS calls that reached our server.

We're expecting to receive ENS update events on any cancellation as defined in the Sep 2020 ENS Dev guide

> Itinerary: "When any itinerary segment data changes (added/deleted/modified)"

While we're waiting for support, I thought I could ask the community if anyone experience the same problem or have any recommendation on where I should look.
Sabre Dev, any pointer you can provide?